# 'service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports' annotation doesn't seems to work as expected

Tags: amazon-eks, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer, argocd

I'm trying to create NLB with ssl certificate with port 443, for my apisix service using argocd app. The problem is that i'm not able to create the alb in port 443 (it creates it only on port 80).

This is the ArgoCd app for the Apisix:

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
name: loadbalancer-apisix
namespace: argocd
annotations:
argocd.argoproj.io/sync-wave: "1"
finalizers:

- resources-finalizer.argocd.argoproj.io
  spec:
  destination:
  namespace: api-gw
  server: https://kubernetes.default.svc
  project: default
  source:
  chart: apisix
  repoURL: https://charts.apiseven.com
  targetRevision: v2.1.0
  helm:
  releaseName: apisix
  values: |
  service:
  type: LoadBalancer
  annotations:
  service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: "nlb"
  service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: tls
  service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-additional-resource-tags: Environment=Prod
  service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: arn:aws:acm:eu-north-1:..........
  This app creates NLB with ssl certificates, but it works on port 80.
```

When I added this annotation:

```
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "https"
```

It doesn't seems to do anything (still creates only port 80).

any idea why?

Environment

AWS Load Balancer controller version
v2.6.0

Kubernetes version
eks 1.27

Answer (score 0):

For TLS termination with Network Load Balancer, Please use below annotations.

```
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "443"
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: external
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-nlb-target-type: ip
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-scheme: internet-facing
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: "arn:aws:acm:us-east-2:185309785115:certificate/7610ed7d-5a81-4ea2-a18a-7ba1606cca3e"
```

Service.yaml

```js
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: MyAppSvc
  namespace: dev
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: external
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-nlb-target-type: ip
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-scheme: internet-facing
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: "arn:aws:acm:us-east-2:185309785115:certificate/7610ed7d-5a81-4ea2-a18a-7ba1606cca3e"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "443"
spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  ports:
  - port: 443
    targetPort: 80
    name: http
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: MyApp
  type: LoadBalancer
```

For more information: https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.4/guide/use_cases/nlb_tls_termination/